# pdflatex stating a lot of files

Tags: pdftex

I was trying to compile a latex document, and it was taking forever.

I thought it was quite strange when a very simple document wasn't almost instant.

When running pdflatex with ptrace, I find it is searching **everywhere** in my home for `texmf`. However, when I run the same command on a different machine, I do not see that occurring.

Below is my document:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

And here is part of the strace:

```
getdents(3, /* 241 entries */, 32768)   = 9048
stat("/home/user/gdb_examples.tar.xz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0660, st_size=1796, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/user/src.tar.xz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=112380084, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/user/tracing-on-linux.pdf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=161222, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/user/ssl_example.pcapng", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4520, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/user/spimsimulator-code", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/user/spimsimulator-code/texmf", 0x7ffee1f6ef40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

This is despite having no variable set for latex indicating to search in `$HOME`.

I'm sure if I did a `mkdir ~/texmf` that this would solve the problem, but my concern is why would latex event *try* to open every file?

Comment: what does `echo $TEXINPUTS` say and `kpsexpand '$TEXINPUTS'` if entered to your shell command line

Comment: `$TEXINPUTS` is empty and `kpsexpand`  produces `.:{/home/cen5848//texmf,!!/etc/texmf,!!/var/lib/texmf,!!/usr/local/share/texmf,!!/usr/share/texmf}/tex/{kpsewhich,generic,}//`

Comment: that's not good...

Comment: Sorry, didn't see a `write(2)`

Comment: the first segment `/home/cen5848//texmf` says to recursively (because of the `//`) search everywhere under home for `texmf` and because of the lack of `!!` it searches the file system rather than relying on a pre-built file list

Comment: it will be set in a file texmf.cnf and you want to edit that out.

Comment: `echo $HOME` shows my home directory containing a trailing / and texmf.cnf adds one. Write it up and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
kpsexpand '$TEXINPUTS'
```

produces

```
.:{/home/cen5848//texmf,!!/etc/texmf,!!/var/lib/texmf,!!/usr/local/share/texmf,‌​!!/usr/share/texmf}/tex/{kpsewhich,generic,}//
```

The problem is `/home/cen5848//texmf` which causes a recursive (`//`) search for texmf below `/home/cen5848` using the file system rather than a mktexlsr file list.

Apparently `$HOME` unexpectedly had a trailing `/` which when concatenated with `/texmf` had the bad effect.

It's normal for `~/texmf` not to have `!!` so that you can drop local files there without having to rebuild the file list each time. Normally the tree there is a lot smaller than the system texmf tree so this is a reasonable compromise. But you don't normally want to have `//` on a tree without forcing kpathsea to use a file list.